# Passing Array from JQuery to PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am attempting to pass an array to php via ajax from jquery, yet its returning nothing in the html return in the alert on success from the ajax.

When setting the type of ajax send to `json` the ajax fails completely, so i have kept it to html as it returns the php page at least.

How do i manage this array on the php end?

**The JS/JQ**

```
var multi = $('.till__tablepanel_table_' + tablenumber + '_row__ticket');
var myarray = [];

$.each(multi, function (index, item) {
    myarray.push({
        name: 'ticket_row_num',
        value: $(item).data('ticket_row_num')
    });
    myarray.push({
        name: 'itemtitle',
        value: $(item).data('itemtitle')
    });
    myarray.push({
        name: 'row_itemid',
        value: $(item).data('row_itemid')
    });
    myarray.push({
        name: 'row_quantity',
        value: $(item).data('row_quantity')
    });
    myarray.push({
        name: 'rowunitprice',
        value: $(item).data('rowunitprice')
    });
    myarray.push({
        name: 'row_total',
        value: $(item).data('row_total')
    });
    myarray.push({
        name: 'measure_type_is_grams',
        value: $(item).data('measure_type_is_grams')
    });

});

//alert(JSON.stringify(myarray));

var url = "http://www.thepantrybromley.com/home/secure/bin/updateDatabase_items.php";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        myarray: myarray
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        // alert("before send");
    },
    success: function (html) {
        alert(html);
    }
});
```

**The PHP**

```
<?
$array=json_decode($_POST['myarray']);
echo $array;
?>
```

Comment: You can't echo an array, you'll just get Array(). Did you try doing a var_dump on $_POST, or inspecting in in developer tools?

Comment: i have not, the return is absolutely nothing not even `array()` currently

Comment: why not use print_r($array); to check first the results

Comment: encode the array using `json` before sending and decode it at the end . That would be right .

Comment: yeah I think I got what you were looking for. Could you pls verify if my answer is correct? I've used foreach and then passed the result in json format if the result has been successful

Comment: indeed it was, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the data in the php side, you may use foreach where the keys are based on your objects in the array passed.

```
<?php  
  $array = $_POST['myarray'];
  if(is_array($array)){
    foreach($array as $item){
      $name = $item['name'];
      $value = $item['value'];

      //your database insert here. just do some validations (like addslashes etc) before inserting
      mysql_query("INSERT into mytable(name,value) values('{$name}','{$value}')")
      or die (
        json_encode(
          array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>mysql_error()
      )));
    }//foreach
    echo json_encode(
      array(
        'status'=>'success'
    ));
  }else{
    echo json_encode(
      array(
        'status'=>'error',
        'message','no data')
    );
  }
?>
```

update: You may echo a json array to get the status of your insert of data
For the javascript side, change your dataType to json

```
var url = "http://www.thepantrybromley.com/home/secure/bin/updateDatabase_items.php";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        myarray: myarray
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        // alert("before send");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if(result.status == 'success'){
         alert('Success')
            }else{
        alert(result.message);
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't encode the array as JSON, it uses URL-encoding. PHP automatically decodes this, so you don't have to use any "decode" function. Just do:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['myarray']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the array using `json_encode()` before sending and decode it at the other end.

```
var encoded_array = json_encode(array_variable);
$.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: url,  
                            dataType: 'html',
                            data: {
                                myarray:encoded_array
                            },
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                // alert("before send");
                            },
                            success: function(html) {
                                alert(html);                        
                            }
                });
```

Comment: You are mixing php and javascript functions. You'd need `JSON.stringify(array_variable)` in javascript.